# Which Filter Do I Use To Modify The Subject Of The Retrieve Password Notification Email?

Tags: filters, email, password

I am looking for the filter that enables me to modify the subject of the "Retrieve Password" notification Email.

If you know which filter to use, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for the `retrieve_password_title` filter.

For example:

```
add_filter( 'retrieve_password_title', 
    function( $title ) 
    {
        $title = __( 'WPSE Custom Password Reset' );
        return $title;
    }
);
```